# Find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
with data as
(select num,
lead(num,1) over(order by num ) as  x1,
lead(num,2) over(order by num ) as x2
from Logs
)select  distinct num as ConsecutiveNums from data
WHERE num=x1 AND x1 = x2;
```

Table: Logs

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| num | varchar |

In SQL, id is the primary key for this table.
id is an autoincrement column.

**
Find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.**

Return the result table in any order.

The result format is in the following example.

Example 1:

Input:
Logs table:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |

Output:

| ConsecutiveNums |
| --- |
| 1 |

Explanation: 1 is the only number that appears consecutively for at least three times.

Comment: I'd consider ROW_NUMBER() over partition etc.

Comment: What's wrong with the attempt you posted?

Comment: its rejecting my testcase @Andrew its only working for the below code

Comment: ```with data as
(select  num,
lead(num,1) over( ) as  x1,
lead(num,2) over( ) as x2
from Logs
)select   distinct num  as ConsecutiveNums from data
WHERE num=x1 AND x1 = x2;```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, Just order the lead by Id instead of ordering on num and you'll get the expected output.

```
with data as
(select num,
lead(num,1) over(order by id ) as  x1,
lead(num,2) over(order by id ) as x2
from Logs
)select  distinct num as ConsecutiveNums from data
WHERE num=x1 AND x1 = x2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to use [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event) to group the steps, and then count those groups (which is rather similar to the double LEAD or LAG solution others have posted:

```
with data(id, num) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 2),
    (7, 2)
), grouped as (
    select
        *
        ,conditional_change_event(num) over (order by id) as cce
    from data
)
select *   
   ,count(*) over (partition by num,cce order by id) as c
from grouped
order by id;
```

gives:

| ID | NUM | CCE | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 2 |

thus to select the 3rd row:

```
select *   
from (
    select
        *
        ,conditional_change_event(num) over (order by id) as cce
    from data
)
qualify count(*) over (partition by num,cce order by id) = 3
order by id;
```

or to select the first row, the counts order can be swapped to `order by id desc`

### simplify your code:

And if you want to leave it in the LEAD/LAG style, the whole SQL can be simplified via a QUALIFY:

```
with Logs(id, num) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 2),
    (7, 2)
)
select distinct
    num
from Logs
qualify num = lead(num,1) over (order by id)
    AND num = lead(num,2) over (order by id)
```